# SQL Server 2008 exclude duplicates from Count

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I wrote a stored procedure that returned results with duplicates.  The COUNT included the duplicates which is incorrect.  How can I get the correct count without including the duplicates.  Below is my scenario.

Account TEST1 has
3 DOCUMENTS attached to it

```
  DOCUMENT1
  DOCUMENT2
  DOCUMENT3
```

Each DOCUMENT may contain multiple conditions attached to it.

```
  DOCUMENT1
    CONDITION1-1
    CONDITION1-2
    CONDITION1-3
    CONDITION1-4
  DOCUMENT2
    CONDITION2-1
    CONDITION2-2
    CONDITION2-3
  DOCUMENT3
    CONDITION3-1
    CONDITION3-2
```

I need to do a total COUNT of DOCUMENTS for Test1.  When I did the COUNT, DOCUMENT1 showed COUNT=4, DOCUMENT2 showed COUNT=3 and DOCUMENT3 showed COUNT=2.  The total count resulted in 9 but should be only 3.

I'm not sure how to write this up to get the correct total count.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct document) from Table
where account = 'Test1'
```